# How to set more than one producer and consumer object using spring kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have created a Kafka topic with three partitions. Using ProducerFactory in Spring-Kafka, I can create a producer instance. But, I want to create three producer instances because I have three partitions. Similarly, I want three instances of consumer. How can I do so? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The `KafkaProducer` javadocs recommend using a single producer within an application so spring-kafka's `DefaultProducerFactory` does just that.

If you don't want to follow the advice of the Kafka javadocs, you can implement your own `ProducerFactory`.

Newer versions of spring-kafka support creating a producer for each thread.

On the consumer sider, the `DefaultConsumerFactory` will create multiple consumers.

If you are using a listener container, simply set the concurrency to 3 and 3 consumers will be created; one per partition.